# Windows 10 local IP address does nont work if network cable is disconnected

Tags: networking, windows-10, bridge

My local LAN which includes my laptop is setup as a static network. I have noticed that when the network cable is disconnected on the laptop I can't ping the laptop from itself. The VMs which are also on the laptop cannot ping the laptop's address from their local bridged addresses.

I can't remember having this problem on Windows 7 and earlier. Is there some fault on my setup or is that the way Windows 10 itself is designed?

Comment: What does the network adapter within the VM show when the network cable from the host is disconnected? If the VM is setup to get an IP via DHCP and its bridged adapter cannot get an IP address well then.... Look over the VM network adapter and TCP/IP settings and see what happens here as you connect and disconnect the network cable from the host machine.

Comment: Although your laptop knows it has a static IP, the packet would still be sent to the gateway and routed back as your laptop has not routing capability for the subnet. You'd only want to ping your loopback address to get a reply, since the packet is sent out to the next hop (the gateway) but never returns due to no connection.or set up a RRAS server with lan routing to allow routing within your local VM subnet. Although I agree the vSwitch 'should' allow the VMs to ping your host without issue in the circumstance